# is there any conference related to meteor js in 2014

Tags: javascript, meteor

is there any conference related to Meteor JS any where in the world in 2014?
I like to learn about about metoer js more.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a programming problem.

Comment: There are Meteor meetup groups in most major cities.

Comment: In future this question would be best suited for the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/meteor-talk), [this](http://meetups.meteor.com) Trello board has a list of meetup groups as @AndrewMao suggested